# Firebase Cloud Messaging : behavior for unused smartphones

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

We are using Firebase to push notification to our users.

Here is the statistics when trying to send a notification to 1000 users that have stopped using our app since 2015 :

```
Android NotRegistered 566
Android success 181
IOS NotRegistered 253
```

It is obvious that almost 100% of such old users should not be not reachable. (That would mean they have our app still installed in their device without having opened it for 5 years).

Statistic for IOS look good.
But as for Android, there are >20% of tokens for which we receive a successful respons which is unrealistic

I suspect the following reason :

When someone has definitely stopped using their device without having removed the app (a new device was bought and the old one was thrown into a drawer), Google still believe it is alive.
Can you confirm, this is the case. If yes, do you know if Google will end up detecting the device is no more in use (with probability 99.9%), maybe if it fails to send our notification after some days ?

Actually, it is useful to have a relevant estimation of how many users I can reach with push notifications.